# CSSLint: Ignore single line in CSS file?

Tags: css, csslint

I'm working with a CSS file that uses Mozilla's -moz-element(#element) directive for a background-image.  The code looks like:

`#foo {background-image: -moz-element(#element);}`

When I run this through CSSLint, it tells me that the "Rule is empty", despite the fact that it's obviously not.  I could attempt to run CSSLint via command line and use --ignore, but what I'm really looking for is a way to ignore just that single line from within my CSS file.  Is there a way to do that?

And just for clarity, what I'm looking for is the analogue to how JSHint does things, which looks like this:

`var notChecked = 'This line won't get checked'; // jshint ignore:line`

Comment: I don't know CSSList, but if it really treats -moz- prefixed names as not there, you might get away with putting this line inside a `@-moz-document` rule. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document).

Comment: Not really looking for a way to hack my code to get it to work with CSSLint (I'd just disable CSSLint completely before I did that).  Looking for an elegant one-line ignore that keeps things nice.  Thanks tho.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to figure out why CSSLint reports a spurious warning for that line, and fix that issue, rather than trying to ignore the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSSLint does not currently support a single-line ignore function from within a CSS file.  Hopefully (would be awesome!) this changes in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Using an embedded ruleset:

```
/*csslint important: false*/

.example {
  display: none ! important 
}

/*csslint important: true*/
```

Comment: Status: **Not worked** for me. //  **1.** It's [**not documented**](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Ignoring-parts-of-CSS-during-linting). // **2.** It doesn't worked, if I needed to ignore 2 or more rules in the same file. [**Example**](https://www.pastery.net/xnusrs/). // Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One can also [ignore](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Ignoring-parts-of-CSS-during-linting#ignoring-whole-sections-of-css) sections with:

```
/* csslint ignore:start */
@import('normalize.css');
/* csslint ignore:end */
```

And also [allow](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Ignoring-parts-of-CSS-during-linting#ignoring-rules-per-line):

```
.foo.bar { /* csslint allow: adjoining-classes */
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: v0.5 came out 5 years ago (July 29, 2011 - v0.5.0). I suggest you upgrade to v1.0.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 1.0.4. For example:  

/* csslint ignore:start */
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
/ * csslint ignore:end */

Comment: The GitHub repository is linked in the answer. Feel free to review the current issues and create a new one if none exists.

Answer (score -2):

In version 0.9.10+ you can use "embedded rulesets" directly in the CSS file.

If that doesn't work, you could try placing that line in a CSS comment, for example:

```
/* #foo {background-image: -moz-element(#element);} */
```

Comment: Do you know how I'd use the "embedded rulesets" to single-out and ignore a solitary line?